# A person/thing that has a good start but fails midway through the journey

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe a thing/person that always shows **potential in the way they start something but fails to follow through to its conclusion**.

Some examples could be:

> - A batsman in Cricket who plays a few good strokes at the start of his innings but then gets out cheaply without making any impact on the outcome of the game.
> - Some technology that looks promising when it's launched successfully. People think it will change the world, etc., but then it fails disappointingly for one reason or another.

Comment: Something that is "Disappointing"?

Comment: @BellaSwan In the way it fails yes, but not in the way it kicks things off.

Comment: I think I've found the word - anticlimactic.

Comment: Sounds to me like _second-act problems_. [link](https://blogs.osc-ib.com/2017/09/ib-teacher-blogs/problems-second-act)

Answer (score 1):

The word is anticlimactic. It popped up in my mind as I recalled some famous sports commentary. Then checked the definition on web and the term aptly describes the situation I had in mind.

Here's **OED's** definition -

***anticlimactic*** - Causing disappointment at the end of an exciting or impressive series of events.

*‘it was an anticlimactic finish to the match’*

Answer (score 1):

A damp squib is a similar concept.

OED - "a situation or event which is much less impressive than expected"

A squib is a firework, which promises exciting things, but then being damp it fails to work properly.

However, it turned out to be a damp squib as the local leaders and even party’s own MLAs remained absent from the programme. [The Times of India]